# Why the product of symmetric-sparse matrices is not symmetric, or dense

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-element

For the equation $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=-(-\Delta)u$ with zero boundary condition  using finite element method. Applying the corresponding weak formulation and taking $v=\phi_{j},j=1,2,...,N$, We obtain the following equation.

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} \frac{du_{i}}{dt}\int _{\Omega} \phi_{i}\phi_{j}d\Omega=-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}u_{i} \int _{\Omega} \nabla\phi_{i}.\nabla\phi_{j}d\Omega\,. $$

Introducing the mass $\mathcal {M}_{i,j}=\int _{\Omega} \phi_{i}\phi_{j}d\Omega$ and stiffness matrices $\mathcal{K}_{i,j}=\int _{\Omega} \nabla\phi_{i}.\nabla\phi_{j}d\Omega$.

Then we have 
$$\frac{d\bf{u}}{dt}=-\mathcal{M}^{-1}\mathcal{K}\bf{u}\, ,$$

so far, we have derived an approximation matrix representation of the Diffusion equation for the finite element method that.is $A=\mathcal{M}^{-1}\mathcal{K}$.

So my question is why $A$ is not only nonsymmetric, also dense.
Although both $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{K}$ are positive-semidefinite and sparse.

Comment: Since $M$ is positive definite you would probably prefer to compute a Cholesky factorization of it. Then in that case, you might rearrange your products to still have a symmetric system. Still, that will change the sparsity of your matrix, then it's probably a better idea to solve the system of equations. Since your mass matrix is constant you just compute the decomposition once and then iterates over time.

Comment: I just want to introduce the matrix approximation to fractional Laplacian by nonfractional Laplacian approxiamtion .  or rather, I would like to use Lanczos approxiamtion to solve the equations.  so  it concerns the property of matrix $A$. @nicoguaro

Comment: $K$ is the approximation to the Laplace operator, not $A$.

Comment: The product of two symmetric matrices is symmetric iff they commute!

Comment: just $A$ i the approxiamtion to the Laplacian ,  is there some vague places what i state about my question above? @nicoguaro

Comment: $K$ is the discrete version of your Laplace operator. Indeed, Laplace equation is just $\Delta u = 0$, that is commonly classified as _elliptic_, while your equation is classified as _parabolic_.

Answer (score 8):

You seem to think that:

1. The product of two sparse matrices is sparse;
2. The inverse of a sparse matrix is sparse;
3. The product of two symmetric matrices is symmetric.

**None of these facts is true**, in general. When it happens, it's the exception, not the rule. Try yourself on some random examples.

It's like believing that $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2$: that would be nice, and a student could intuitively expect it, but unfortunately it's true only in very special cases.

Comment: I know that a product of symmetric matrices is seldom symmetric and the inverse of a sparse matrix is usually dense.  But for illustration, could you give a proof about that discussion above.   @Federico Poloni

Comment: Trying with random examples might work as a proof, since they would be counter examples.

Comment: @J. Xie, you might be interested in learning that any unsymmetric matrix can be expressed as a product of two symmetric matrices. (See e.g. [this](http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2012/07/02/symmetric-pair-decomposition/).)

Comment: Thanks for your answer !  I just want to develop some algorithm to solve some equations with the representation of non- symmetric matrix  about factual problems@J.M.

Comment: The product of sparse matrices **is** sparse. It's just typically **less** sparse than what you started with.